# What does the letter k mean in the documentation of solve_ivp function of Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, scientific-computing

Solve_ivp is an initial value problem solver function from Scipy.
In a few words

> scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method=’RK45’, t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, args=None, **options)
>
> Solve an initial value problem for a system of ODEs.
> This function numerically integrates a system of ordinary differential equations given an initial value.

In the solve_ivp function documentation (Scipy reference guide 1.4.1 page 695) we have the following

> Parameters
> fun [callable] Right-hand side of the system. The calling signature is fun(t, y). Here t is a scalar, and there are two options for the ndarray y: It can either have the shape (n,); then fun must return array_like with shape (n,). Alternatively, it can have the shape (n, k); then fun must return an array_like with shape (n, k), i.e. each column corresponds to a single column in y. The choice between the two options is determined by the vectorized argument (see below). The vectorized implementation allows a faster approximation of the Jacobian by finite differences (required for stiff solvers).

Here **n** stands for the no of *dimensions* in y.
What does **k** stand for? This might seem a very naive question for those who know the answer. But please, believe me, I really could not find it (at least not in the documentation).
[The great hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993352/7952027) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54991056/7952027) seems to shed some light. But well, IMHO it still is too dark to move around.

Comment: This is still a good question, if you've found an answer it's perfectly okay to post it as an answer here, and if so please ping me so I can both read and up vote it. *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh, you can follow this question.

Comment: @DanielWalker I've never figured that following stuff out, out but I'll look into it now, *thanks!*  **update:** oh! there's a button for it right there :-)

Comment: You should see the options "share", "edit", "follow", etc. below the tags.

Comment: I don't still have a  good answer to this question@uhoh

Answer (score 0):

Well, y kan depend on other variables, say x.

y generally stands for n fields.
If n = 3 then y = numpy.array([u, v, w]) and this means that u, v and w can all depend on x.

k is the number of values that x can have.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this answers the question, or challenges my answer in the link.  It needs a working demonstation.

Comment: I agree with you that it remains to be demonstrated.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/651a9b717deb68adde9416072c1e1d5aa14a58a1/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py#L123) you can find how "vectorized" is implemented. It seems to me that an entire row of y is passed on.

Comment: Your link creates two attributes, `fun_single` and `fun_vectorized` - in different ways depending on the parameter.  Actual use is by the `method` code.  I'm guessing that `fun_single` is used for the objective evaluation, and `fun_vectorized` is used for jacobian evaluations (if the method so desires).  Either way the user provided `y0` is supposed to be 1d, and the objective returns a matching size result.  The purpose of `vectorized` is to enable more efficient evaluation of the jacobian (objective gradients).

Comment: I am still not sure. I will need to run this through a debugger to get a handle on this.

Comment: y0 must be of shape (n,), so 1d, but y can have dimensions (n,k).
In both cases (`vectorized=True` or `False`) we have:

`self._fun = np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)`
.
If `vectorized=True` we have `fun_single(t, y) = (np.asarray(fun(t, y[:, None]), dtype=dtype)).ravel(); fun_vectorized = np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)`

So it seems to me that `self.fun_single` passes on y (but with shape (n, 1, k) instead of (n, k)) for a given t to `fun`. It returns a flattened (1d) array.