# How to Use Scipy Optimize Vectorized Parameter

Tags: python, scipy, vectorization

I found in the [release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.9.0.html#new-features) from scipy to version 1.9.0 the following about the optimisation module, in the section "scipy.optimize improvements", 4th point:

> Add a vectorized parameter to call a vectorized objective function only once per iteration.

However, I already checked out the documentation for such parameters (for the minisation function and minize_sclar) and couldn't find any hint for such a parameter. While searching in the internet I only found some posts concerning some suggestions or GitHub-issuses to implement such a thing (or workarounds for that).

Where is this parameter to find and can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those notes have a more specific note for `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`.  That parameter is explained there.  I've also come across it in other SO questions, but I don't recall which functions use it.

Basically for functions that allow it, you can write an objective function, or other callable (jacobian, boundary?), in a way that takes a 2d array of values.  Normally the function just takes a 1d array, the current "state".  But with "vectorized=True", the function should be prepared to accept a set of "state" array, and return a value for each.

So instead of calling the objective `k` times to get a range of value, such as when calculating a gradient, it can call it one, with a (n,k) argument, and get back all `k` results with one call.

I tried to explain how `solve_ivp` uses this at

[scipy.integrate.solve_ivp vectorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991056/scipy-integrate-solve-ivp-vectorized)