# Scipy integrate (quad, quadrature, nquad) cannot integrate vector-parameterized functions? (equivalent function works in MATLAB)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, scipy, integral

I'm converting some code from MATLAB to python, and am struggling to get a function that takes array arguments (as parameters) to integrate using Scipy.

I've reduced the code to a basic example that produces the same error in Scipy, while the equivalent MATLAB code functions as expected.

I'm trying to pass a row vector parametric argument of length M and a column vector parametric argument of length N to the function being integrated over a further, separate, integration argument, with the expectation that my integrated output will have the shape MxN.

The following python code produces this error:

```py
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py", line 196, in quadrature
    if err < tol or err < rtol*abs(val):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

from

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate


c = np.array([1, 2], ndmin=2)
r = np.array([2, 1])
r = r[:, np.newaxis]

def fun(p, c):
    p1 = np.zeros(c.shape)
    mask = np.array(np.sqrt(np.pi/(2*c)) < 1, ndmin=2)
    p1[mask] = np.arccos(np.sqrt(np.pi/(2*c[mask])))

    d = np.zeros(c.shape)
    mask = np.logical_and(np.abs(p) > p1, np.abs(p) <= np.pi/2)
    d[mask] = 1/(np.pi/(2*c[mask]**2) +
                     ((np.cos(p1[mask]) - np.cos(p))/2))
    return(d)

def intgd(p, r, c):
    A = np.ones((np.size(r), np.size(c)))

    c_bcr = np.broadcast_to(c, (np.size(r), np.size(c)))
    r_bcc = np.broadcast_to(r, (np.size(r), np.size(c)))

    s = np.sin(r_bcc) - np.sin(p)
    A[s != 0] = np.sin(c_bcr[s != 0]*s[s != 0])/(c_bcr[s != 0]*s[s != 0])

    return 1/fun(p, c)**2*(A**2)

res, err = integrate.quadrature(intgd, -np.pi/2, np.pi/2,
                                         args=(r, c), vec_func=True)
```

The equivalent MATLAB code (which outputs an MxN shaped result) is

```matlab
c = [1, 2];
r = transpose([2, 1]);

out = integral(@(p)intgd(p, r, c), -pi/2, pi/2, 'ArrayValued', true);

function intgd = intgd(p, r, c)

    c_bcr = repmat(c, length(r), 1);
    r_bcc = repmat(r, 1, length(c));

    A = ones(length(r), length(c));

    s = sin(r_bcc) - sin(p);
    A(s ~= 0) = sin(c_bcr(s ~= 0).*s(s ~= 0))./(c_bcr(s ~= 0).*s(s ~= 0));
    intgd = 1./fun(p, c).^2.*(A.^2);
end

function d = fun(p, c)

    p1 = zeros(1, length(c));
    mask = sqrt(pi./(2*c)) < 1;
    p1(mask) = acos(sqrt(pi./(2*c(mask))));

    d = zeros(1, length(c));
    mask = abs(p) <= p1; 
    d(mask) = 1./(pi./(2*c(mask).^2) + cos(p));
    mask = and(abs(p) > p1, abs(p) <= pi/2);
    d(mask) = 1./(pi./(2*c(mask).^2) + ((cos(p1(mask)) - cos(p))./2));

end
```

The MATLAB output `out` from the above is

```
[6.58727018139280,  0.963083280848789;
6.78600314283299,   1.05994693990888]
```

I'm unsure how `scipy.integrate.quadrature` is dealing with the dimensions of objects being passed through it, but the idea is that it should be producing the same MxN output.

I'm aware that `numpy` has its own built in broadcasting that generally avoids the need for explicit broadcasts as shown here, but I'm uncertain about how it deals with arrays where M=N, as in this case, so I've kept it explicit.  Any pointers on this secondary issue would also be welcome.

Comment: `integrate.quadrature` expects a scalar function, not an array one.  The `vec_func` just tells it that the function will accept multiple `p` values (and return a like sized array).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991056/scipy-integrate-solve-ivp-vectorized, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893336/numerical-quadrature-of-scalar-valued-function-with-vector-input-using-scipy

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions. I'll have a look and report back. Do you think ```nquad``` is what is needed, based on the description and code?

Comment: I've also reviewed the documentation for ```nquad``` based on the comment response to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893336/numerical-quadrature-of-scalar-valued-function-with-vector-input-using-scipy , but it seems from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html that this is not really what I'm looking for; ```nquad``` is a ```quad``` wrapper that allows integration over multiple integration arguments - it returns a ```float``` so that cannot produce the desired output.

Comment: I may not have outlined the question precisely. In my example, I want to integrate over the integration argument ```p``` while passing ```r``` and ```c``` as parametric (vector-valued) arguments that are not integrated over, but are simply passed into the function, with each value passed concurrently for each integration over ```p```. The output is then a vector with a size related to  ```r``` and ```c```. This is what the MATLAB code achieves.

Comment: I've been looking into ```quadpy``` (https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) as well but so far unable to understand how this may relate to my problem.